# Cut and paste content to next unknown named sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want cut some lines of my activesheet and paste it to the next sheet. But i will never know the name of the next sheet.

Tried it:

```
Range("1:26").Cut After:=ActiveSheet
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("1:26").Cut Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Range("A1")
```

or

```
Range("1:26").Cut Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Range("1:26")
```

if you want moving them in the same position...

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub cutandpaste()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    
    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:26")
    Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Next.Range("1:26")
    
    r1.Cut r2
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub another()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("1:26").Cut .Next.Range("1:26")
    End With
End Sub
```